# Converting G2M3 and G2M2 encoded Videos (GoToMeeting Videos) to a video type that FFMPEG supports

Tags: php, ffmpeg, video-encoding, mencoder, video-codecs

I'm developing a PHP application that uses `FFMPEG-PHP` to split videos and convert them to `FLV`. And I ran into this problem :
`FFMPEG` does not support `G2M3` or `G2M2` encoded videos, and I have to make the process of splitting and converting videos effortless for the client, I don't want him to convert the video locally before uploading to the server.
All I want to do is to find a way to convert the `G2M3` encoded videos **online** to `FLV` or to any other video type that `FFMPEG` supports.
So, is there any way I can do that?
Can `MEncoder` handle this type of videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried doing something similar and could not find a solution. The only workaround I could get together was to use an older version of Windows Media Encoder (think it was version 9), which would let you convert to a different format.

The big hassle was that the GotoMeeting codec was only available on Windows (and maybe Mac). A possible workaround could be to setup GotoMeeting to record using standard WMV, which is not the default setting.

Answer (score 0):

G2M3 is a proprietary codec, see this link on [vlc-forum](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?p=222446#p222446). As the thread says, you will not find a open-src implementation of it.

Google gives me this link for a [conversion](http://blog.zevdesigns.com/post/518878143/the-g2m3-fix) howto